# Print Unicode characters in C, using ncurses

Tags: c, string, gcc, unicode, ncurses

I have to draw a box in C, using ncurses;

First, I have defined some values for simplicity:

```
#define RB "\e(0\x6a\e(B"  (ASCII 188,Right bottom, for example)
```

I have compiled with gcc, over Ubuntu, with `-finput-charset=UTF-8` flag.

But, if I try to print with addstr or printw, I get the hexa code.
What I`m doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the code you are using to print?

Comment: Have you considered using the ncurses `border` function?

Comment: Also, you don't need `-finput-charset=UTF-8`, first because it will be the default and second because there is not a single non-ascii character in your source code (or at least, the part you are sharing with us), and that is what `-finput-charset` refers to: the character set of the source code itself.

Answer (score 3):

`ncurses` defines the values `ACS_HLINE`, `ACS_VLINE`, `ACS_ULCORNER`, `ACS_URCORNER`, `ACS_LLCORNER` and `ACS_LRCORNER`. You can use those constants in `addch` and friends, which should result in your seeing the expected box characters. (There's lots more ACS characters; you'll find a complete list in `man addch`.)

`ncurses` needs to know what it is drawing because it needs to know exactly where the cursor is all the time. Outputting console control sequences is not a good idea; if ncurses knows how to handle the sequence, it has its own abstraction for the feature and you should use that abstraction. The ACS ("alternate character set") defines are one of those abstractions.

Answer (score 3):

A few issues:

- if your program writes something like `"\e(0\x6a\e(B"` using [addstr](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html), then ncurses (*any* curses implementation) will translate the individual characters to printable form as described in the [addch](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Adding-characters) manual page.
- ncurses supports line-drawing for commonly-used pseudo-graphics using symbols (such as `ACS_HLINE`) which are predefined characters with the `A_ALTCHARSET` attribute combined.  You can read about those in the [*Line Graphics*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Line-Graphics) section of the `addch` manual page.
- the code `0x6a` is ASCII `j`, which (given a VT100-style mapping) would be the lower left corner.  The curses symbol for that is `ACS_LRCORNER`.
- you cannot write the line-drawing characters with `addstr`; instead `addch`, [`addchstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addchstr.3x.html) are useful.  There are also functions oriented to line-drawing (see [`box`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_border.3x.html) and friends).
- running in Ubuntu, your locale encoding is probably UTF-8.  To make your program work properly, it should initialize the locale as described in the [Initialization](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) section of the ncurses manual page.  In particular:

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  Also, your program should link against the ncurses**w** library (`-lncursesw`) to use UTF-8, rather than just ncurses (`-lncurses`).
- when compiling on Ubuntu, to use the proper header definitions, you should define `_GNU_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, I'm probably arriving late to the party but I'll give you some additional insight that might (or not) shed some light and skills for your "box drawing" needs.

As of 2020 I'm involved in a funny project on my own mixing Swift + Ncurses (under OSX for now, but thinking about mixing it with linux). For the moment it's working flawlessly...

The thing is, as I'm using Swift, internally it all reduces to "importing .h and .c" files from some Darwin.ncurses library the MacOS Xcode/runtime offers.

That means (I hope) my newly acquired skills might be useful for you because apparently we're using the very same .h and .c files for our ncurses needs (or at least they should be really similar)

Said that:

---

As of now, I "ignored" ACS_corner chars (I can't find them under swift/Xcode/Darwin.ncurses runtime !!!) in favour of pure UTF "corner chars", which also exist in the unicode pointspace, look:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

What does it mean? Whenever I want to use some drawing box chars around I just copy&paste pure UTF-8 chars into my strings, and I send these very strings onto addstr.

Why does it work? Because as it was mentionend in a previous answer, before initializing ncurses with initscr(), I just claimed "I want a proper locale support" in the form of a setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); line.

What did I achieve? "Comfortable magic", as I just only need to copy+paste "box chars" inside my "normal strings".
Working with Darwin.ncurses/OSX Mojave I'm getting, not only "bounding box chars", but also full UTF8 support.

Try the "setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); initscr();" approach and tell us if "drawing boxes" works also for you under a pure C environment just using UTF8 bounding box chars.

Greetings and happy ncursing!

Comment: FYI: That person, Thomas Dickey, is involved in the development of ncurses. See https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html for more information.